# LINQ query on List of enums

Tags: linq, dictionary, enums

I want to get a subset of enums from an enum, to later select a random enum element based on the values of a Dictionary. I tried doing this:

```
    var allEnums = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)).Cast<MyEnum>();
    var availableEnums = allEnums.Where(e => SomeClass.SomeDictionary[e] < someThreshold);
    //Note: SomeDictionary<MyEnum, int>
```

Also, this does not work either:

```
    var availableEnums = SomeClass.SomeDictionary.Where(entry => entry.Value < someThreshold);
```

The value of availableEnums is always {System.Linq.Enumerable+c__Iterator1D`1[[AircraftModel, Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]}. I must be doing something very stupid, but how do I get this correct?

Comment: If I get what you're trying to achieve, you need to project the results of your query with a .ToArray() or ToList() if you want a collection. the Where and other linq extensions return a sequence. You need to look into deferred execution.

Comment: Do the dictionary contains weight for each enum?

Comment: @reckface thanks, .ToList() did the job, together with a .FindAll(...). I think I need to take a closer look at .Where, I thought it was just like .FindAll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to use

```
var availableEnums = SomeClass.SomeDictionary
                      .Where(entry => entry.Value < someThreshold)
                      .ToList();
// or
var availableEnums = SomeClass.SomeDictionary
                      .Where(entry => entry.Value < someThreshold)
                      .ToArray()
```

FindAll was before the Linq extensions and projects results immediately, whereas Where is deferred, which allows you to efficiently chain multiple operations like OrderBy, Take and so on before projecting your results.